# Kick users out of an application

Tags: notifications

I have written an application that is used company wide. A lot of users have the tendency to leave the application open 24-7. This application is under development constantly as the Marketing department's needs change. Most changes are minor but often times need to be implemented quickly. Salesmen are often away from their desks or on the phone, so an intercom announcement does not always do the trick. The application is housed on a network file share and shortcutted to.

What I envision is something like a message popping up something like "The program will exit for an update in five minutes, please save your changes now." Is there a way to display this message and kick them from the exe remotely? I thought of maybe just having a database value that it checks periodically to see if an update is pending, but that seems like a cheap hack to me.